# wcstof precision

Tags: c++, type-conversion

```
#include <cwchar>
float flt_Value = wcstof(L"0.8", nullptr);
```

Why does this return 0.800000012? Is there a way to get a more precise result from wcstof()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get a more precise result from wcstof()?

Not using `wcstof`, which will return the best representation of the string as a single-precision, floating point number (see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/10871073)).

However, you *can* increase the precision by using the `double` type for your variable, and calling the `wcstod` function.

The following short program will demonstrate the difference (on most platforms):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cwchar>

int main()
{
    float flt_Value = wcstof(L"0.8", nullptr);
    printf("%12.10f\n", flt_Value);               // 0.8000000119
    double dbl_Value = wcstod(L"0.8", nullptr);
    printf("%12.10lf\n", dbl_Value);              // 0.8000000000
    return 0;
}
```

Note: On systems that support an extended-precision `long double` type (mine doesn't), you can further extend the precision as follows:

```cpp
    long double ldbl_Value = wcstold(L"0.8", nullptr);
    printf("%22.20Lf\n", ldbl_Value);
```

Here is the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcstof) for the three conversion functions used.